# Can't Install Any Office Product (Service Office Software Protection Platform Won't Start)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

I had Office 2016 installed and I went to reinstall it because I was having some issues. Now when I try to install I get the following error

> Error 1920. Service 'Office Software Protection Platform' (oppsvc) failed to start'

When I go to manually start the service I get

> Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified

Which is strange because I can see the file path to `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform\OSPPSVC.EXE"` exists

I have tried changing the Log-On as for the service to be my account or Local System Account but it does not work.

I even tried to install Office 2013 and I get the exact same issue.

How can I install any version of Office if I cannot get past the installation?

Comment: [Error message when you try to install Office 2010: "Error 1920. Service 'Office Software Protection Platform' (osppsvc) failed to start.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2401987)

Comment: Already tried that, still get same error

Comment: You ran this `icacls "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform" /grant "Network Service:F" /t`?

Comment: Yes and it said it changed 8 files but I still cannot start service

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: I do not have any version of Office installed. The problem is that I cannot get past the office installation

Comment: Did you try deleting the file? And any other Office remains?

Comment: The file is only there once I go to install Office

Comment: Any update on this?  I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: I have luckily faced the exact same issue. I might be late but I just found the solution for all the people still facing this issue. Open your registry editor(Win+R and then type "regedit" and hit enter). Then go to this location "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options". Under this folder there will be another folder called "osppsvc.exe". This is what is blocking your "osppsvc.exe" file from executing. Just delete this folder and you are good to go. Office will now install. Unfortunately my reputation is not high enough to write an answer

Comment: @DenverBraganza your answer worked for me, thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome @Radius

Answer (score 0):

It is a issue with the Software Protection service.  I had this issue forever and tried many different solutions online to fix this; many MS uninstallers, 3rd party, different versions of Office from 2010, 2013, 2016, etc.

This is what finally fixed it (also if need be manually start your Software Protection Service):

Drop this into a command prompt that you are running as an administrator:

```
icacls "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform" /grant "Network Service:F" /t
```

It should give you the output similar to this:

```
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform\OSPPC.DLL
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform\OSPPCEXT.DLL
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform\osppobjs-spp-plugin-manifest-signed.xrm-ms
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform\OSPPOBJS.DLL
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform\OSPPSVC.EXE
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform\OSPPWMI.DLL
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform\OSPPWMI.MOF
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform\TBD1695.tmp
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform\TBD1696.tmp
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform\TBDE044.tmp
processed file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtecti
onPlatform\TBDE054.tmp
Successfully processed 12 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

After that, I was able to get both Office 2016 and 2013 installed.

Comment: Someone in the comments suggested exact same thing and it did not work

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question and it's comments again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try:
In Services, make sure OSPPSVC is not disabled.
Run CMD, enter: sc config "osppsvc" start= demand